# a PDF reader which can read notes on PDF

Tags: ios, applications, pdf

I am looking for a PDF reader on iPhone which can read notes on PDF.

I tried Adobe Reader(see below), which does not work in this way. [image]

Answer (score -1):

I found answers, two apps work, I provided the screenshots for each app as well.

1. Documents
   [image]
2. Foxit pdf
   [image]